# Beam comparison height versus width question. Please help

Tags: beam

First post, do not know if anyone here is qualified to answer.

I am trying to find an accurate comparison of two beams of equal strength but different dimensions.  The answer will be a PROVEN real world example that passed code by an inspector, OR a PROVEN mathematical relationship.  I have scoured the internet but no one seems to have written anything about it that I can locate.

Example:  I KNOW that a four 2x12's fastened together will easily carry some amount of deck load.  What I want to know is HOW MANY 2x6's fastened together will carry the same load.

Answers that do nothing:

Answers that in the form of "I think..." or "I believe" or "Probably what would work"  or "you could do it this way or that way with this material or that material.   No.  Useless.  If you do not know the answer then no answer of any type is excellent.  Answer that try to tell or educate me about modulus of elasticity or bending force.  I know about all that and do not require a class on it.  I want a simple practical example of a proven job or the proven mathematical relationship.

What will answer my question:  "I did a project exactly like that where I placed 12 boards side by side and it passed code by an inspector instead of using a beam of double height"

OR

The mathematically proven relationship is, for wood, 1/2 the height means you have to increase to 4.323 times the width to get the exact same load capacity.

I understand you will not be able to answer the question, so if you can't, don't.  I want an expert, a contractor or engineer (not a civil engineer) intelligent summary of the results and nothing more.

Comment: Is there a reason you're limiting yourself to dimensional lumber?

Comment: You sure are making a lot of demands for people that answer questions out of the goodness of their hearts. Perhaps you should hire an engineer where you can pay for them to put up with your attitude.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it violates our [code of conduct](https://diy.stackexchange.com/conduct). Please keep questions welcoming and respectful of others.

Answer (score 3):

Beam strength goes directly as the width (twice as wide is twice as strong) and as the cube of the depth (you call height), so twice as deep is 8 times as strong.

The mathematics of nominal lumber are annoying, (2X12 and 2X6 are not any of those dimensions) but your ballpark is going to be 4 2x12 is 8 times as strong as 4 2x6, so you'd need 32 2x6 for the equivalent strength.

The short and sweet of which is if you need 4 2x12's worth of strength in 6" height, use steel.

Comment: Yeah, solid sawn (dimensional) lumber is *not* structurally efficient (if anyone questions me, they should go look at the span tables for TJIs sometime)

Comment: I don’t think your “ballpark” answer is what the op wanted. (Plus your “rule of thumb” using 8 times is wrong. See my calculations.)

Answer (score 2):

Beams are calculated two ways: 1) ultimate load, and 2) working stress.

Determining the maximum load (or ultimate load) or as you called it “maximum strength” is determined by calculating three issues: 1) bending stress, 2) shear stress, AND 3) deflection.

I’ll use spruce, pine or fir (SPF) with normal (standard) grade, which covers most of the construction industry.

1. Bending Stress is based on the stress of a given quality of material (species and grade) AND the geometric shape at the cross section. This stress is also known as the “Extreme Fiber in Bending” because you are checking the fiber of the wood at its extreme outer edges (top in compression and bottom in tension). A common grade for SPF is 1500 psi under normal conditions of loading as established by West Coast Lumbermen’s Bureau.
2. Shear Stress is also called “Horizontal Stress” because you are checking the fiber stress in the horizontal direction. To illustrate this stress: stack 3 - 2x4’s flat up on 2 chairs about 10’ apart. Then stand in the middle and you’ll see that the boards tend to slide past each other. A common grade for horizontal stress for SPF is 120 psi.
3. Deflection is the stress that tends to make a beam bend. If a beam is overloaded it can bend so much that it’s noticeable and unsightly.

So, to answer your question, beams with short spans tend to fail in horizontal shear, beams with extra long spans tend to fail in deflection and middle span beams tend to fail in Extreme Fiber in Bending.

So you want to compare 4-2x12’s to 2x6’s. Let’s take 10’ span.

1-2x12 can take 3580 lbs.
4-2x12’s can take 14,320 lbs. max

1-2x6 can take 790 lbs.
So, to equal 4-2x12’s spanning 10’ you’d need 14,320/790 = 18-2x6’s

There are other factors, like impact loading, uniform distribution loading, multiple span loading, dynamic (moving) loading, etc.

Obviously the biggest factor is the span.

Comment: By the time you're done buying all those 2x6s, plus the 2x4 to make the posts to support them, it would have been cheaper to buy a steel beam and steel posts and rent a crane to put them in place! Never mind trying to run any sort of mechanicals past them.

Comment: Yes thank you that answers my question.  Amazing how difficult it is to filter out the wannabees with the knowing people.  Going with steel as the wood prices have tripled since the post and eliminate using wood at all.  Even the mod thought they should let the dullards answer instead of pre filtering them out and wasting real peoples time.